# Is "citizen" a short for "citizenship" in the US?

Tags: slang, abbreviations

A friend of mine said that the word "citizen" is commonly used by Americans as a short form of "citizenship". Is it true? I couldn't find this usage in any online dictionary, thesaurus or slang glossary. I'm not sure in what context my friend meant, perhaps a slang...

Edit: For clarification: *besides* its actual meaning of "the member of a state" or "one who possess citizenship", can citizen *also* be used as a short for "citizenship" in America, perhaps as a slang? Like: in "A foreign woman gets American citizen if she marries an American".

Comment: A **citizen** is someone who currently possesses **citizenship**. I'm as citizen of the US because I have US citizenship. It's not short for anything. It is it's own word. Both nouns with similar, different meanings.

Comment: Surely, but I mean: besides meaning "a member of a state", can "citizen" also be a short for "citizenship"?

Comment: No. It's not used as a shortened version of citizenship. **Citizenship** is ***the act of being a citizen***. How can *citizen* ever mean *the act of being a citizen*?

Comment: No.  There are very few situations where one word could be substituted for the other and still retain the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you both. Concluding, I guess my friend just made up this sense to not admit a mistake.

Comment: A foreign woman gets an American citizen for a husband if she marries an American. Then she may become eligible to apply for citizenship.

Comment: @Hank:  You might want to be careful about making broad, sweeping generalizations about the English language.  As [Laurence says](//english.stackexchange.com/q/361585/26083#361591), “Such shortenings are not uncommon, … but this particular one is [not] correct…”  *Citizen* can mean *the act of being a citizen* if people start to use it that way.  One might rhetorically ask, how can *day* be defined so that a day can be composed of day and night?  How can *orange* mean *the color of an orange*?  Etc.

Comment: @Scott Touché. You make a valid point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it isn't.  Such shortenings are not uncommon, and don't always hold up under grammatical analysis.  But this particular one is neither correct nor used in the vernacular.